# How can i use siri by using command line on terminal?

Tags: terminal, siri

I want to use siri by using terminal command. is it possible?
Example:

```
$ siri "Sleep my mac"
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Interacting with Siri via the command line in macOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39759230/interacting-with-siri-via-the-command-line-in-macos)

Answer (score 1):

You can use siri setting up Samantha's voice on Settings>Accessibility>Speech

Open the terminal and type $ say "Whatever you want"

You can check more (as save the output) here: http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/siri-voice-mac/